# Xcode Clang Formatter Does Not Recognize AlignConsecutiveAssignment

Tags: ios, xcode, format, clang, clang-format

Adding this line to the clang-format file gets me an error (basically rejecting the keyword).

AlignConsecutiveAssignment: true

My goal is obviously to have the = operator alingned in consecutive statements like:

```
a        = true;
blueish  = false;
```

What is the way to obtain this with the latest stock Xcode 6.3.1?

Thanks...

Comment: The directive is really "AlignConsecutiveAssignments"... Still not accepted by Xcode's 6.3.1 clang-format tool..

Comment: This is still not working in ClangFormat 3.9